# double status bar for iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk

I want to add double status bar state in my app, like 'in call' or internet tethering
so far I imported SBStatusBarController.h and

```
static Class $SBStatusBarController;

[[$SBStatusBarController sharedStatusBarController] setDoubleHeightMode:2 glowAnimationEnabled:YES bundleID:@"com.test.test"];
[[$SBStatusBarController sharedStatusBarController] setDoubleHeightStatusText:@"test" bundleID:@"com.test.test"];
```

put this code into my app.
but still double height bar won't show up.
What am I missing?
(I am very novice, I'd be very appreciated if you be detailed)

Answer (score 0):

This worked prior to 4.0.

The new statusbar classes are now in `UIKit`, specifically `UIStatusBar`. Dig around in those frameworks and you should be able to get this up and working.